# Which kind of functors preserve the bar-construction?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-algebras, higher-category-theory, koszul-duality

Let C, D be monoidal infinity categories that admit geometric realizations.

Let $F: C \to D$ be a monoidal functor and A an augmented associative algebra of C.

Denote $Bar(A)= \mathbb{1} \otimes_A \mathbb{1} = colim_{\Delta^{op}} A^{\otimes n} $ the bar-construction of A.

We want to study when the canonical map $\alpha: Bar (F(A)) \to F(Bar(A)) $ is an equivalence. Certainly this is satisfied if F preserves geometric realizations.

Are there weaker conditions that guarantee that $\alpha$ is an equivalence?

I' am especially interested in the following situation:

Let D be a stable presentably symmetric monoidal infinity category and O an operad in D.

Let C be the category of O-algebras with divided powers in D.

The forgetful functor $C \to D$ preserves finite products and so can be considered as a symmetric monoidal functor $F: C \to D$, when C and D are endowed with cartesian symmetric monoidal structures.

In general the forgetful functor $C \to D$ does not preserve geometric realizations and I want to know when F preserves the bar-construction with respect to the cartesian symmetric monoidal structures, i.e. F sends the bar-construction to the suspension.

Equivalently I would like to know if the bar-construction with respect to the cartesian symmetric monoidal structure defines an equivalence $ Mon(C)\to C$, where Mon(C) denotes the category of monoids in C.